# Extraer numero del diccionario como Int

Tags: python

Intento extraer el numero del valor del diccionario pero no lo consiguo sacar como int que necesito.

```py
print(contador['Attributes'])
#Respuesta
{'ApproximateNumberOfMessages': '30'}


print(contador['Attributes'].values())
#Respuesta
dict_values(['30'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo como key `ApproximateNumberOfMessages`, puedes acceder a él de la siguiente forma:

```
# Suponiendo que se almacene en la variable diccionario
diccionario = {'ApproximateNumberOfMessages': '30'}
# accedo a su value:
print(diccionario['ApproximateNumberOfMessages'])
```

De esta forma, imprime `30`.

**¿Qué sucede?** Que no es un `int`. Si usamos el método `type`:

```
print(type(diccionario['ApproximateNumberOfMessages']))
```

**Verás que devuelve**:

```
<class 'str'>
```

Por lo que **podrías cambiarlo de la siguiente forma**:

```
valor = int(diccionario['ApproximateNumberOfMessages'])
```

**Si imprimes**:

```
print(type(int(diccionario['ApproximateNumberOfMessages'])))
```

Verás **que devuelve**:

```
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Este es un ejemplo con un diccionario cuya llave es `'Attributes'` y el valor es otro diccionario. Si deseas obtener la lista de todos los valores del segundo diccionario, convertidos a enteros, puedes utilizar la función `map`. En el caso que sólo desees obtener el valor convertido a entero de una de las llaves del segundo diccionario, puedes hacerlo con `int(contador['Attributes']['llave_del_segundo_diccionario'])`

```
contador={'Attributes':{'ApproximateNumberOfMessages': '30'}}

results = list(map(int, contador['Attributes'].values()))
print(results)
# Respuesta
# [30]

print(int(contador['Attributes']['ApproximateNumberOfMessages']))
# Respuesta
# 30
```